# Get the actual url HASH in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I know that this is impossible via PHP supervars, but see this website:

When we navigate on the pages, the title and meta just changes and this affect the facebook too, see:

How he is doing it? I have a ajax navigation system too, and need to set og, but I don't know how to do dinamically as he did.

Just a comment, he have hidden INPUTS with values of the meta:

But I still don't know how he can parse this before the website being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The URL fragment is NEVER sent to the server. It is used as a reference by the browser. "Traditionally" it is used to scroll to an element with the ID referenced by the fragment, however more recently it has been given some more exotic uses.

In particular, `#!` is a shebang, and has the meaning that "this page is being loaded by AJAX, but if you load the following relative to the domain, you will get the full page anyway" - this is particularly useful for search engines.

Basically, use AJAX combined with `location.hash` to get it to work.

Comment: I already have this working, my problem is with the og:* and title tags to be dinamyc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Facebook is recognising the shebang and retrieving the appropriate URL, which contains the relevant meta tags - possibly through PHP's `echo` function.

Comment: http://www.novomp3.com.br/?_escaped_fragment_=show&id=60 I have a aproppiate url too, the google simulator get the url perfectly, but the facebook doesn't read as this is. See the code of this page and see there: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.novomp3.com.br%2F%3F_escaped_fragment_%3Dshow%26id%3D60

Answer (score 0):

it's just some js(jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var current_page = '';
    $("a").live("click", function(){
        return change_hash(this,1);
    });
    function change_hash(el,type) {
        if(type==1) {
            var link = $(el).attr("href");
        }
        else
        {
            var link = el;
        }
        var link_ar = link.split('/#!');
        if(link_ar[1]!=undefined) {
            if((link_ar[1].length>3)&&(link_ar[1].substr(0,1)=='/')) {
                window.location.hash = '#!'+link_ar[1];
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    $(function(){
        $(window).hashchange( function(){
            address = location.hash.replace("#!","");
            var skip=false;
            if((address.substr(0,1)=='/')&&(address!=current_page)) {
                $("#content").html('<div class="content-box"><div class="ajax-loading">carregando...</div></div>');
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                if (address.indexOf(".php") == -1) {
                    var newaddress = address.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+/g,"");
                    if('/'+newaddress!=address) { change_hash('/#!/'+newaddress,2);skip=true; }
                    address='/PerfilDetalhe.php?user='+newaddress;
                }
                if(skip==false) {
                    $.get('http://www.suamusica.com.br'+address,    function(htmldata) {
                        $("#content").html(htmldata); 
                        document.title = $('#metaTitle').val();
                        $('meta[name=description]').attr('content', $('#metaDescr').val());
                        $('meta[name=keywords]').attr('content', $('#metaKeywords').val());
                        $('meta[property="og\\:description"]').attr('content', $('#metaDescr').val());
                        $('meta[property=og\\:title]').attr('content', $('#metaTitle').val());
                        $('meta[property=og\\:url]').attr('content', $('#metaURL').val());
                        $('meta[property=og\\:image]').attr('content', $('#metaImage').val());
                        $('meta[property=og\\:type]').attr('content', $('#metaType').val());
                        $('meta[name=DC\\.title]').attr('content', $('#metaTitle').val());
                        $('meta[name=DC\\.description]').attr('content', $('#metaDescr').val());
                        $('meta[name=DC\\.subject]').attr('content', $('#metaKeywords').val());
                    }).fail(function() { $("#content").html('<div class="content-box error-box"><h1>Ooops!</h1><p>A página acessada não existe ou não foi encontrada.</p></div>'); });
                    current_page = address;
                }
                $.get('http://www.suamusica.com.br/msg_check.php',  function(resp) {
                    if(resp==1) {
                        $('#msg-notify').show();
                    }
                    else $('#msg-notify').hide();
                })

                 $('.tipsy-s').remove();
            }
        });
        var loc_h_n = window.location.hash.replace("#", "").replace("!", "").replace(".do", ".php")
        if(window.location.hash!='#!'+loc_h_n&&window.location.hash!='') {
            window.location.hash = '#!'+loc_h_n;
        }
        $(window).hashchange();
    });
</script>
```

as you can see he returns false on clicks and acts based on the hashtag value